# assign person to seats

Tags: php, algorithm

I want to assign 100 persons to 100 seats for 3 days with PHP.

There are 10 VIP seats, 40 classA seats and 50 classB seats. 5 persons have a VIP ticket, 45 have a "classA" ticket, and 50 have a "classB" ticket.

The following rules apply:

```
-Persons with a VIP ticket can only be seated on VIP seats
-Persons with a classA ticket may be seated on VIP seats
-Persons with a classB ticket can only be seated on ClassB seats
and seats should change for each day
```

Is there any algorithm (possibly in pseudocode) for this problem?

Comment: Let's see what have you thought so far.

Comment: first i try "foreach" loop through tickets but VIP seat fill with calssA  ticket

Comment: then 3 loop, one through VIP seat and find VIP ticket(if not find random calssA) , another through classA and also classB, but one person assigned to VIP and classA ticket at same day

Comment: Why not posting  the code you wrote? Please, take some time to read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to fit the requirements to avoid more downvotes or get your question flagged/closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All classB tickets are assigned to classB seats. So on the first day you assign them in sequence, the next day you shift them to the right, putting the rightmost person on the left most seat, and you repeat the same for the last day's seating.

For VIP tickets, you use the 5 first VIP seats, and apply the same shift method for those 5 seats.

For the classA tickets, you choose 5 lucky ones: they get VIP seats on all 3 days: you apply the shifting method for those 5 tickets on the 5 remaining VIP seats.

The 40 other classA tickets are put on the classA seats, and again you shift them around each next day.